# Getting FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed error while running python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to run below python script.
I'm getting error. I tried my best to resolve for didn't get rid off from this problem.

ususally this kind of problem doesn't come. I tried with warning module.
Please guide me how can i tackle by this problem.

Can you please help me?

python Script:

```
import pandas as pd
import subprocess
import sys
import warnings
import os
import time
import datetime
import pwd
import logging
import uuid
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import csv
import pwd
import numpy as np
from boto3.s3.transfer import S3Transfer
from parameter_file_input import *
#warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
file_to_df = '/home/hadoop/medaff/Metadata/Join_metadata.txt'
def join_condition(TableName):
    meta_df = pd.read_csv(file_to_df, delimiter='|')
    #meta_df.set_index(['0'], inplace=True)
    meta_df = meta_df[meta_df['TableName']==TableName]
    if meta_df.empty == True:
        return ''
    seq_max = int(meta_df['Sequnce'].max())
    query = ''
    print(query)
    for i in range(1, seq_max+1):
        counter = 0
        meta_df_temp = meta_df[meta_df['Sequnce'] == i]
        for index,row in meta_df_temp.iterrows():
            query+=' '
            print(query)
            if pd.isna(row['operator']):
                print("Operator Null")
                if counter==0:
                    if pd.isna(row['Aliastable']):
                        print("Aliastable Null")
                        query += row['jointype']+' '+row['Childtable']+' on ('+row['Parenttable']+'.'+row['columnname']+'='+row['Childtable']+'.'+row['child column']+' and '
                    else:
                        print("Aliastable not Null")
                        query += row['jointype']+' '+row['Aliastable']+' '+row['Childtable']+' on ('+row['Parenttable']+'.'+row['columnname']+'='+row['Childtable']+'.'+row['child column']+' and '
                else:
                    query += row['Parenttable']+'.'+row['columnname']+'='+row['Childtable']+'.'+row['child column']+' and '
            else:
                print("Operator not Null")
                if counter==0:
                    if pd.isna(row['Aliastable']):
                        print("Aliastable Null")
                        query += row['jointype']+' '+row['Childtable']+' on ('+row['Parenttable']+'.'+row['columnname']+' '+row['operator']+' '+row['Childtable']+'.'+row['child column']+' and '
                    else:
                        print("Aliastable not Null")
                        query += row['jointype']+' '+row['Aliastable']+' '+row['Childtable']+' on ('+row['Parenttable']+'.'+row['columnname']+' '+row['operator']+' '+row['Childtable']+'.'+row['child column']+' and '
                else:
                    query += row['Parenttable']+'.'+row['columnname']+' '+row['operator']+' '+row['Childtable']+'.'+row['child column']+' and '
            counter+=1
        counter = 0
        query = query[:0-len(' and ')]+')'
        query = query.lstrip(')')
    return query
print(join_condition('TERR'))
```

error:

```
/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py:1649: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  result = method(y)
```

Comment: can you add full traceback? What line causes that warning?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh only this is coming in screen. No addition info is not coming.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh did you get the solution?